# abort trap when using matplotlib.pyplot after import caffe in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, caffe, macos-sierra

My problem is that it occurs an abort trap when using matplotlib.pyplot after import caffe however there is no problem if using matplotlib.pyplot before import caffe.I run this with python2.7 on macos10.12.4.
Here is my wrong code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#encoding=utf-8
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import caffe
plt.plot([0,1],[0,2])
plt.show()
```

The output is:

```
src/tcmalloc.cc:284] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x7feb5f158af0
Abort trap: 6
```

There will be no problem like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#encoding=utf-8
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,1],[0,2])
plt.show()
import caffe
```

But i need to use plt after 'import caffe'.
How to fix it?

Comment: I find that if i import caffe before import matplotlib.pyplot then the problem will be solved, but don't know why.

Comment: I found your question after reading this https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/5961 because I'm hitting the same problem with xarray (`src/tcmalloc.cc:331] Attempt to free invalid pointer`)…